# Angular Universal 9 in Production: Views Error

Tags: angular, universal

I am attempting to setup my Angular 9 app (w Angular Universal 9) for production on Digital Ocean's Ubuntu 18.04, but am met with a frustrating error: `Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory [...]`. This issue does not occur locally.

My `dist/` contains two directories, `browser` and `server`, and I start with: `pm2 start client/dist/client/server/main.js`.

For reference, my `server.ts` is out-of-the-box:

```
import {ngExpressEngine} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';

import {AppServerModule} from './src/main.server';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
import {existsSync} from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/client/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, {req, providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl}]});
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4003;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

Any advice would be welcome! Please let me know if I can post any other helpful details. Tks!

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for anyone working on the same problem.  I found a solution by changing the directory where I executed the run to: `node dist/client/server/main.js`. Quite frankly, I don't know why this works better at this parent position, but it worked. Tks!